# Extra spacing problem in 4K resolution android device

Tags: android, android-layout, visual-glitch

I am developing chat application android. It works pretty well in all the devices.

But 4K resolution devices like Samsung s8+ and one plus 6t, It leaves right side extra spacing automatically.
I have not given any, margin and padding.

refer [[image: this screenshot]].

my view file is something like this:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/sender_bg"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/karla_regular"
            android:text="Yes, and it will be safe. My promise"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

can any one help me with the solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: check this [Support different screen sizes](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes)

Comment: Did you try to make the linear layout width match parent ? @BomberMan

Comment: @KhaledQasem Thank's mate. it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the linear layout width match parent

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/sender_bg"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/karla_regular"
            android:text="Yes, and it will be safe. My promise"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```